# Hardware status with ESXi shows incomplete hardware info; wrong BMC details

Tags: vmware-esxi, ipmi, drac

I have an ESXi host that's part of a cluster of identical Dell R710 servers. One of the servers in the "Hardware" tab shows an incomplete list of hardware sensors, and under the BMC node, shows totally the wrong details:

[image]

Wrong wrong wrong wrong wrong! That's not the right IP address, that's not a valid gateway and that isn't even the right MAC address. Not even close.

So far I have:

- Reset sensors
- Reset the iDrac
- Run `/sbin/services.sh restart` on the ESXi host
- Removed and re-entered the IPMI information on `Configuration > Software > Power Management`

How can I correct this so that I'm seeing accurate hardware information from within ESXi?

Comment: Any chance of evicting this node and re-adding it to the cluster?

Comment: Not immediately; but I could plan maintenance to do it but not for a while unfortunately. Although it's been like this for months and I've only just got to it on my todo list, so it's not like I'm in a huge hurry.

Comment: Does BMC's utility show it right? http://www.bmc.com/it-solutions/atrium-discovery-dependency-mapping.html - there's apparently a bug that could cause this.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but I reply for future reference: it can be related to an old/bugged iDRAC/BMC firmware. Try updating them.

Answer (score 0):

What does `Configuration > Software > Power Management` show you in the vSphere client?

If the results are unexpected, try modifying them there and see if that influences the Hardware Status tab.

[image]

Comment: It has the correct values in there. Oh, I also tried blanking the details out and re-entering them. It took a very long time to commit the changes, but didn't make any difference.